# Why am I getting an index out of range in my code?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code for part of a connect 4 program:

```
def place_piece(n,column):

    col=int(column)
    boardlist=[['.'*42]]
    for l in range(7):
        if boardlist[col+42-7l]=='.':
            if n%2==0:
                piece=X
            else:
                piece=O
            boardlist[col+7(6-l)]=piece
            break
    return boardlist

print(place_piece(1,3))
```

When I run it, line 5 `if boardlist[col+42-7l]=='.':` has an index out of range error. Why? And how could I fix this?

Comment: why are you casting an int to an int? That cannot be your code because it would error long before you try to index

Comment: What is `boardlist` supposed to be? Because I'm guessing a one-element list containing a one-element list containing a string consisting of 42 full stops isn't it...

Comment: Wait then how do I make a 42 element list? @jonrsharpe

Comment: You mean `['.' for _ in range(42)]`?

Comment: ok and i deleted the second line and I still get the same error... thanks though! @PadraicCunningham

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCH i was so confused and did not what I was doing @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index out of range error means that the index of the array you are referring to doesn't exist. This is how you declared `boardlist`:

```
boardlist=[['.'*42]]
```

In this case, `boardlist` itself only contains one element, which happens to be another array. Thus, the only viable index would be `boardlist[0]`. Based on the code you posted, I would suggest changing it to this:

```
boardlist=['.']*42
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `col+42-7l` is more than `len(boardlist) - 1` at some point in your loop. As simple as that.